# QT QML how to break out a given layout

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I have a default layout with a header, footer, left and right margin and a content area - all rectangles with fixed sizes and positions.

[image]

Depending on the program, the content area is dynamic divided into any number of subareas (column layout with rectangles). These subareas are to be visually separated. The separator should go beyond the content area.

[image]

How can I give the separator the outer left (x) position from rectangle 2 as start position? With x: 0 it doesn't work, x :0 will be the left (x) position of the content and not the hole screen.

I have already tried with a negative x value for the separator but it remains in the content area

Comment: Hope this link https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-visualcanvas-coordinates.html helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a working example. Notice, how setting `x` property of `seperator` to negative works.

In QML, elements are drawn in the order they are defined in the code, with the last element being drawn on top of the other elements. This is because QML uses a painter's model for rendering, where each element is drawn on top of the previous element in the order they are defined.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: rootwindow
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: leftRect
        x: 0; y: 0
        width: 40; height: 400
        color: "red"
        border {
            width: 1; color: "white"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: topRect
        x: 40; y: 0
        width: 320; height: 40
        color: "red"
        border {
            width: 1; color: "white"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: botRect
        x: 40; y: 360
        width: 320; height: 40
        color: "red"
        border {
            width: 1; color: "white"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rightRect
        x: 360; y: 0
        width: 40; height: 400
        color: "red"
        border {
            width: 1; color: "white"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: context
        x: 40; y: 40
        width: 320; height: 320
        color: "gray"
        clip: false
        Column {
            id: row
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 10
            Repeater {
                id: repeater
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: 1
                Rectangle {
                    id: delegate
                    width: parent.width
                    height: repeater.count > 1 ? (parent.height - (repeater.count-1) * row.spacing) / repeater.count
                                               : parent.height
                    color: "blue"
                    Rectangle {
                        id: seperator
                        x: -leftRect.width
                        y: parent.height
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        width: parent.width + leftRect.width + rightRect.width
                        height: row.spacing
                        color: "black"
                        visible: index !== repeater.count-1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: row
            onClicked: {
                repeater.model = repeater.count+1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]